# Whats happening with my pond pump at reduced voltage?

Tags: power, motor

So, I wanted to slow down my pond pump, and I have a variac or variable transformer that I used to reduced the voltage going to pump. I guess I probably needed to vary the frequency, not the voltage to control the speed, but the pump does slow down as I turn the voltage down, maybe due to less torque? But, around 54% voltage or so, the motor spins down or dies off completely, but right as it would stop, something clicks and the motor boost, but begins to die again, beginning a perpetual cycle. I suppose a capacitor inside the motor is switching on and off as it begins to spin down. But, I want to know whats happening here, does the voltage reduction lower motor speed? Why can't I reduce the voltage past 54% without starting this cycling? Will running the motor at a reduced voltage shorten it's life?

Comment: what do you mean "something clicks"?

Comment: That kind of motor is designed to run only at a particular speed. If you want variable speed, you need a different type of motor altogether.

Comment: As to this being off topic here, I was designing a system in which I felt a variable transformer effected my solution. I wanted to know about unexpected behavior I experienced. I didn't ask for instructions. If this stackexchange is for microelectronic design only, it shouldn't be called electrical engineering, because electrical engineering is a wider field than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds as though this is a single phase, capacitor start, AC induction motor. Quite common in the 1/4 to 1/2 horsepower range.

When running at full speed, a single field coil is energised at 50Hz (or 60Hz depending on where you are) and this field coil does two things : (1) it acts as the primary of a transformer, transmitting current to the rotor (which acts as the secondary) and (2) provides the magnetic field against which the rotor current's field pushes to turn the motor.

But to start, this AC field has to act against a stationary rotor, and that imparts no direction to the motor - you could start it spinning either way round equally well.

So to give it direction, a second field winding (the starter winding) is connected via a centrifugal switch and a capacitor; the capacitor resonates with the winding inductance to phase shift the AC current in the starter coil, and this defines the direction of rotation. As the motor spins up to speed, the switch opens, and disconnects the starter winding. This also protects the starter capacitor, which is not rated to survive continuous operation.

So the click you hear is the centrifugal switch turning on again to reconnect the starter. A few cycles of this in a few minutes will probably overheat and destroy the starter capacitor.

Answer (score 2):

The click is probably the starter switch kicking in again.  This is not a good thing to happen repeatedly.  Keep the voltage high enough so that the pump runs reliably.

Depending on the type of motor, it will also be less efficient at low speed.  That is also not a good thing since is causes excess heat and you get less water pumped for the power used.

How about modulating the pump flow by turning it on some fraction of the time every 5 minutes or so?  Two minues full on followed by three minutes full off is a lot better than running in-between somewhere.

Comment: +1 for the periodic on/off operation. I was going to suggest a VFD but that doesn't overcome the starter problem.

Comment: I really just wanted to slow down my waterfall.

Comment: @Motes: Do you really need to burn carbon, make nuclear waste, or create other environmental problems just to have a waterfall?

Comment: @OlinLathrop To be or not to be, that is the question.